# Highlight duplicates based on 2 different columns

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

let's say that's my excel data:

| PersNr | Surname | Travel Type | Departure date | Trip ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 578123 | Smith | Abroad trip | 03.05.2023 | 1 |
| 578123 | Smith | Abroad trip | 04.05.2023 | 2 |
| **574754** | Jones | Abroad trip | **22.05.2023** | 3 |
| **574754** | Jones | Dom. trip | **22.05.2023** | 4 |
| 541255 | Brown | Abroad trip | 28.05.2023 | 5 |
| 543241 | Abrams | Abroad trip | 28.05.2023 | 6 |

What I want to achieve is go through each row and highlight rows when it detects duplicate based on PersNr and Departure date. I want to highlight every person that has more than 1 trip on the same day (the best would be if it would also take into consideration that travel type must differ, but that's not important). Built-in duplicate detection tool would only search based on 1 column. I tried some tricks with conditional formatting, but no result. I have over 4000 rows and it would save me a lot of time.

/edit
added trip id column

Comment: Use a conditional formatting rule with `COUNTIFS`

Comment: But won't it show me only rows that are exactly the same? I forgot to mention there are different columns with different content, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a rule based on `COUNTIFS`. The `"<>"&$C2` checks if the Travel Type is different.

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A2,$D:$D,$D2,$C:$C,"<>"&$C2)
```

[image: applied to]

Comment: Thanks, although I had to replace D2 with D1 etc. Without it, the highlight had offset of 1 row, no idea why, but after change it works like a charm. Thank you :)

Comment: You can use D1 if you apply the rule starting in row 1, or D2 if you start in row 2. I did the latter, as you can see in the "applies to" in the screenshot.